# Check "ModelState.IsValid" only on certain part of the Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET-MVC Core 2.1 and I have this `ViewModel` class in my code

```
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            Section1 = new HomeSection1ViewModel();
            Section2 = new HomeSection2ViewModel();
        }

        public HomeSection1ViewModel Section1 { get; set; }
        public HomeSection2ViewModel Section2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeSection1ViewModel
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeSection2ViewModel
    {
        public HomeSection2ViewModel()
        {
            Details = new List<HomeSection2DetailViewModel>();
        }

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public List<HomeSection2DetailViewModel> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeSection2DetailViewModel
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number")]
        public int? Sequence { get; set; }
        public DatabaseAction Action { get; set; }
    }
```

My view page will bind `HomeViewModel` as its `Model`, my question is how do I validate only certain part of the `Model`? For example I want to validate `Section2` but not `Section1` in my Controller. How do I achieve that?

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? (are you trying to create some kind of wizard?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: My real class have a lot of section (properties) and I don't want to create multiple Views so I use the same model and just break it down like `if(section == "2") then { //show section2 controls }`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke maybe he wants to separate sections but don't wanna use a new model for each.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: Exactly

Comment: If you do not include form controls for `Section1` then it will be `null` and no validation will be done for `Section1`

Comment: But you will need to remove the constructor. (but why don't you just use `HomeSection2ViewModel` in the the view rather than `HomeViewModel`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Because all sections share the same View

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Works, thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HomeViewModel` has a constructor which initializes both the `HomeSection1ViewModel` and `HomeSection2ViewModel` properties. The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes an instance of `HomeViewModel` in the POST method and calls its constructor which means that both `Section1` and `Section2` properties are initialized, but because you are only posing values for only one, the other will be invalid because of the validation attributes applied to its properties.

Remove the constructor from `HomeViewModel` so that only `Section2` is initialized by the `DefaultModelBinder` (based on values from the request). `Section1` will be `null` by default, therefore no validation is performed on any of its properties.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by client-side authentication and not server-side.
Else you could override your model.

```
public class BaseModel
{
   [Required]
   public string RequiredProperty { get; set; }
}


public class DerivativeModel : BaseModel
{
    new public string RequiredProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Enjoy;)

Comment: Or Create its own viewModel

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will be binding your HomeViewModel to different Views and in some Views you want to validate some properties as mentioned.

There are multiple approaches to get this done, here are 2 I can think of:

1- Implement IValidatableObject in your ViewModel

```
public class HomeSection2ViewModel : : IValidatableObject
{
    public HomeSection2ViewModel()
    {
        Details = new List<HomeSection2DetailViewModel>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Header { get; set; }
    public bool Validate { get; set; }
    public List<HomeSection2DetailViewModel> Details { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      if(Validate)
      {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title)
          {
               yield return
                    new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "required",
                        memberNames: new[] { "Title" });
          }
      }
    }
}
```

2- Or Bind each View to a version of the ViewModel with the required validation and use **AutoMapper** to map the Model to the ViewModel or the ViewModel to another ViewModel.